# Switching catkin workspaces carries old env vars

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, environment-variables, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Often I want to switch from my main catkin workspace `oldws` to sandbox workspace `newws`. But sourcing `setup.bash` in newws keeps adding oldws into some environment variables. As shown below, unsetting those and sourcing again doesn't help. Is there any other possible flaws??

```
rosman@rosmachine:~/oldws$ rm -fR build devel
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ rm -fR build devel
(on a new terminal)
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ catkin_make
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ source devel/setup.bash
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ env |grep oldws
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/newws/devel/lib:~/oldws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/groovy/lib
CPATH=~/newws/devel/include:~/oldws/devel/include:/opt/ros/groovy/include
PATH=~/newws/devel/bin:~/oldws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/groovy/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PYTHONPATH=~/newws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:~/oldws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/newws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:~/oldws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/groovy/lib/pkgconfig
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/newws/devel:~/oldws/devel:/opt/ros/groovy
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ 
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ unset CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH 
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ unset ROS_PACKAGE_PATH 
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ unset CPATH 
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ unset PYTHONPATH 
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ unset PKG_CONFIG_PATH 
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ env |grep oldws
PATH=~/newws/devel/bin:~/oldws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/groovy/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ source devel/setup.bash 
rosman@rosmachine:~/newws$ env |grep oldws
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/newws/src:~/oldws/src:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/newws/devel/lib:~/oldws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/groovy/lib
CPATH=~/newws/devel/include:~/oldws/devel/include:/opt/ros/groovy/include
PATH=~/newws/devel/bin:~/oldws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/groovy/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PYTHONPATH=~/newws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:~/oldws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/newws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:~/oldws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/groovy/lib/pkgconfig
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/newws/devel:~/oldws/devel:/opt/ros/groovy
```

Using Groovy on Quantal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53669/switching-catkin-workspaces-carries-old-env-vars/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin uses env caching when you create your devel space first (some people don't like that it does). This means when you create an initial build, e.g. using catkin_make, then what is in your env goes into a file that is used to create the same env next time you source the setup.*sh.

The solution for you is to delete newws/devel, then start a clean terminal (one in which oldws is not in env), and catkin_make (or cmake) new_ws.

If you don't like env caching after playing with it, give feedback.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-30**:
Thx. Yes I like to at least give out my opinions. I'll look for the corresponding tickets from github http://goo.gl/QQFtU but if someone can point out the right place for me that's great.